Segfault when requesting accessibility permission via macOS Accessibility API
I'm trying to create a Rust program that will ask for accessibility permission on macOS.
If the permission is granted (through Settings -> Privacy & Security -> Accessibility), then it works and returns true from AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions.
But if the permission is not allowed, instead of prompting to ask for the permission, the program crashes with a segfault.
It seems the settings dictionary is created incorrectly, but I'm not sure why.
I created it by following AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions Apple's docs and tested it on macOS 14.4.1 (Apple silicon).
use accessibility_sys::AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions;
use core_foundation_sys::base::{CFRelease, TCFTypeRef};
use core_foundation_sys::dictionary::{CFDictionaryAddValue, CFDictionaryCreateMutable};
use core_foundation_sys::number::kCFBooleanTrue;
use std::ffi::CString;
use std::ptr;

fn main() {
    let mut is_allowed = false;
    unsafe {
        let options =
            CFDictionaryCreateMutable(ptr::null_mut(), 1, std::ptr::null(), std::ptr::null());
        let key = CString::new("AXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt").unwrap();
        let value = kCFBooleanTrue;
        CFDictionaryAddValue(options, key.as_ptr().as_void_ptr(), value.as_void_ptr());
        is_allowed = AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions(options);
        CFRelease(options as *const _);
    }
    println!("Accessibility permission enabled: {}", is_allowed);
}


Why is there no error checking whatsoever? CFDictionaryCreateMutable might return NULL for example, you should check for that.

CString::new("AXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt").as_ptr().as_void_ptr() is not acessibility_sys::kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt but the documentation tells us that's the only valid key when a dictionary is passed to CFRelease.

It's probably a good idea to use the higherlevel acessibility and core_foundation crates instead of the low level bindings with the _sys suffix.

Thanks for the help in the comments, I used accessibility_sys::kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt instead of my own CString and now it doesn't crash! also added error handling
use std::{error::Error, ptr};
use accessibility_sys::{kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt, AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions};
use core_foundation_sys::dictionary::{CFDictionaryAddValue, CFDictionaryCreateMutable};
use core_foundation_sys::base::{CFRelease, TCFTypeRef};
use core_foundation_sys::number::{kCFBooleanFalse, kCFBooleanTrue};


fn check_accessibility(ask_if_not_allowed: bool) -> Result<bool, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let is_allowed;
    unsafe {
        let options =
            CFDictionaryCreateMutable(ptr::null_mut(), 0, std::ptr::null(), std::ptr::null());
        let key = kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt;
        let value = if ask_if_not_allowed {kCFBooleanTrue} else {kCFBooleanFalse};
        if !options.is_null() {
            CFDictionaryAddValue(
                options,
                key.as_void_ptr(),
                value.as_void_ptr(),
            );
            is_allowed = AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions(options);
            CFRelease(options as *const _);
        } else {
            return Err("options is null".into());
        }
    }
    Ok(is_allowed)
}

fn main() {
    let is_allowed = check_accessibility(true).unwrap();
    println!("Accessibility permission enabled: {}", is_allowed);
}

